# Copy and Paste Cell Values in Excel VBA: Compile and Run Time Errors

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am working in excel VBA to set up a recurring code that will copy formula values out of one worksheet and paste the values into a running list on another worksheet. I can copy and paste the formulas into the desired location, but what do I need to change in this code to copy and paste the values only?

I've tried a variety of variations on this code:

1. `.Value` after the copy and/or paste command at the bottom
2. `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` (which gives the compile error, expected end of statement)
3. `.Value` when defining the cells to copy (which gives Run-time error '438')
4. Changing the `Dim` type of my copy and paste variables to Variants, Strings, and Range

---

```
Sub snapShot()
    Dim sourceSheet As String, destinationSheet As String
    Dim copyR As Range, copyT As Range
    Dim pasteR As Range, pasteT As Range
    sourceSheet = "REPORT"
    destinationSheet = "Historical Changes"

    Set copyR = Worksheets(sourceSheet).Range("I2")
    Set copyT = Worksheets(sourceSheet).Range("I3")

    With Sheets(destinationSheet)
        Set pasteR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 1)
        Set pasteT = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 2)
    End With

    copyR.Copy pasteR.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Compile Error: Expected: End of Statement
    copyT.Copy pasteT.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Compile Error: Expected: End of Statement
    pasteT.Columns(2) = Now() 'This gives a time stamp next the my columns
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("24:00:00"), "snapShot"

End Sub
```

If I remove the `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` my code will work properly to copy and paste the formulas, but since I want time stamped data, I only want the values, not the formulas. 
I am currently getting

> Compile Error: Expected: End of Statement

If I change it to `.Values` I get

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Please let me know if you see anything that will fix this! I'm sure it's something simple, but I've been stuck for a while on this one.

Comment: Put the pastespecial on a new line

Comment: Or just `pasteR.value=copyr.value`.

Comment: @SJR pasteR.Value=copyR.Value Fixes it. Thank you! I figured it was probably something simple. 
    'pasteR.Value = copyR.Value
     pasteT.Value = copyT.Value

Comment: Tip, Maybe @SJR should post the suggestion as an answer, or you can self-answer the question for closure instead of changing the title. The first option would return credit to the helper. =)

Comment: @SJR if you submit this as an answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `PasteSpecial` this bit needs to be on a separate line to the `Copy`, as in:

```
copyR.Copy
pasteR.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

In this particular case, one can avoid the clipboard altogether and directly transfer the value, which is shorter in code, and in operation. As in:

```
pasteR.value=copyR.value
```